# A limit to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n^2 + 2}{n^2 + 3}\right)^{n + 2}$$

Does somebody know how to solve this limit to infinity?
Thank you in advance.

---

The solution is $e^{1/2}$.

Comment: How can the limit be greater than $1$ when you are raising a positive number less than one to an integer power greater than $1$. Every $n$ gives a number less than $1$ and the limit as written should be $1$.

Comment: @Anja97 Solution is not $e^{1/2}$, it is $1$. See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bn+%5Cto+%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2+%2B+2%7D%7Bn%5E2+%2B+3%7D%5Cright%29%5E%7Bn+%2B+2%7D&dataset=)

Comment: Now I know why I kept getting 1 as a solution ... and I thought it's wrong since the math book says the solution is e^1/2. Thank you for noticing!

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $$\frac{n^2+2}{n^2+3}=\frac{n^2+3-1}{n^2+3}=1-\frac{1}{n^2+3}$$